# LINQ: Retrieve model data after GroupBy on joined data

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, group-by

After joining 3 tables/model/entity I could simply retrieved data from view model. But when I assigned a GroupBy I was not able to then I can not get the data in a normal way. I need to get data from the grouped data.

```
var modelList =
          from model1 in db.Model1
          join model2 in db.Model2 on model1.id equals model2.model1_id
          join model3 in db.Model3 on model2.id equals model3.model2_id
          where ((model1.id== 2) && (model.menu_id== 3)) 
          orderby subMenu.SUBMENU_NAME
          select new USER_ACCISSIBLE_SUBMENUE_VIEWMODEL
                      {
                       MODEL_VIEW_MODEL1 = model1,
                       MODEL_VIEW_MODEL2 = model2,
                       MODEL_VIEW_MODEL3 = model3
                      };

        string myData= "";
        foreach (var item in modelList )
        {
         myData+= item.MODEL_VIEW_MODEL1.COLUMN1 + item.MODEL_VIEW_MODEL2.COLUMN2 + item.MODEL_VIEW_MODEL3.COLUMN3;
        }
```

Till now this worked simply.
   But after the follwing line I am getting error with the for-each loop. I have given a generalized form of my requirement. I also tested by placing GroupBy  with the  modelList LINQ rather than using modelListGrouped  variable. But  same error. Item can not find the viewmodels when use GroupBy clause. I need to retrieved data from grouped element.

```
var modelListGrouped = modelList .GroupBy(x => x.MODEL_VIEW_MODEL1.id);
foreach (var item in modelListGrouped )
        {
         myData+= item.MODEL_VIEW_MODEL1.COLUMN1 + item.MODEL_VIEW_MODEL2.COLUMN2 + item.MODEL_VIEW_MODEL3.COLUMN3;
        }
```

Comment: If it is possible, show us input and the desired output.

Comment: The GroupBy is creating a collection for the value of the group.  So you need to use a Select to enumerate through the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<T>>`. So your foreach should look like this:

```
var modelListGrouped = modelList .GroupBy(x => x.MODEL_VIEW_MODEL1.id);
foreach (var group in modelListGrouped )
{
    // group is now the IEnumerable<T> you had before
    // but also knows group.Key by which this was grouped
    foreach(var item in group)
        myData += item.MODEL_VIEW_MODEL1.COLUMN1 + item.MODEL_VIEW_MODEL2.COLUMN2 + item.MODEL_VIEW_MODEL3.COLUMN3;
}
```

`GroupBy` returns an enumeration of `IGrouping`. These have their grouping `Key` and represent an enumeration of the items that are part of this group.

Comment: Thanks :) it worked . but can you also tell how to apply distinct on the model.menu_id  without group?

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman I don't exactly know what you mean...maybe better to open a new question?